# Network resource as local developement

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, php, webserver

I am using **Windows 8.1** as host operating system. I have installed **Ubuntu** on Virtual box as guest and **PHP7** installed in it. I want to use **PHP7** as local development on Windows. Is it possible to use **PHP7** and PHP built-in server installed on my guest machine in my Windows over **ssh** or any others?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Either by forwarding port or accessing VM via IP address.

So may consider to use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) with private network configuration, see example [`Vagrantfile`](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/):

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/vivid64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.22.22"
  config.vm.hostname = "vagrant"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", id: "core", nfs: true
end
```

then when you provision your VM by `vagrant up` and your Apache server with PHP is up, then access your server via above IP address or by host which you can add into your [`hosts`](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/modify-your-hosts-file) file, like:

```
192.168.22.22 local.dev
```

In addition, having `config.vm.synced_folder` set-up, your files in selected folder (`.`) on host machine are synched and automatically available in VM under `/vagrant` via [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System).

If you need to access your VM, simply run: `vagrant ssh` in folder with your `Vagrantfile`.

Check the following Vagrant configurations: [mycognitive/drupal-sandbox](https://github.com/mycognitive/drupal-sandbox/blob/master/Vagrantfile), [geerlingguy/drupal-vm](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm) ([Drupal VM](http://www.drupalvm.com/)) for further ideas.

Comment: I want to keep my development files on host machine rather than guest.
I am already doing this with IP forwarding by keeping files on guest os.

Comment: I dont know any thing about vagrant, I am trying it.

Comment: @MdAdil You can keep development files on host machine by synching the folder (`config.vm.synced_folder`), I've added it into the answer.